# The instance of entity type 'x' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 6}' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, cqrs

I am working a asp .netcore 6.0 clean architecture project.

When I try to update a site, I got this error,

**System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'SiteCode' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 6}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.**

Before We use services, in there this same code worked fine. Now we move to clean architecture(CQRS and Mediatr). I used same update code but I got this error.

**.AsNoTracking()**
I tried with
`var result = await _DbContext.SiteCodes.FindAsync(request.Id).AsNoTracking();` this line,

But got error as,

`'ValueTask<SiteCode?>' does not contain a definition for 'AsNoTracking' and no accessible extension method 'AsNoTracking' accepting a first argument of type 'ValueTask<SiteCode?>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Application]`

Here is my codes

UpdateSiteCommandHandler.cs

```
public async Task<SiteCode> Handle(UpdateSiteCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = _mapper.Map<SiteCode>(request);

        _DbContext.SiteCodes.Update(result);  // goes to exception after this line

        await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return result;
    }
```

GetSiteByIdQueryHandler.cs

```
public async Task<SiteCode> Handle(GetSiteByIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        var result = await _DbContext.SiteCodes.FindAsync(request.Id);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(SiteCode), request.Id);
        }

        return result;

    }
```

controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] UpdateSiteCommand command)
        {
            command.Id = id;

            var siteCode = await _mediator.Send(new GetSiteByIdQuery(Id: id));

            var result = await _mediator.Send(command);
            
            return Ok(result);

        }
```

DependencyInjection.cs

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PerformanceBehaviour<,>));  // I tried with AddScoped() But not work
       
        return services;
    }

}
```

in DbContext

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var entries = ChangeTracker
                .Entries()
                .Where(e => e.Entity is AuditableEntity && (
                        e.State == EntityState.Added
                        || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

            foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
            {
                if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    ((AuditableEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    ((AuditableEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedBy = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Entry((AuditableEntity)entityEntry.Entity).Property(p => p.CreatedAt).IsModified = false;
                    Entry((AuditableEntity)entityEntry.Entity).Property(p => p.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                }

                ((AuditableEntity)entityEntry.Entity).ModifiedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                ((AuditableEntity)entityEntry.Entity).ModifiedBy = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? null;
            }

            var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken)

         return result;
        }
```

Anyone has idea how can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core uses ChangeTracker to detect changes in loaded entities, and better (not faster) solution is to load entity for update.

```cs
public async Task<SiteCode> Handle(UpdateSiteCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // the following code will load entitiy if it is still not loaded.
    var dbRequest = await _DbContext.SiteCodes.FindAsync(request.Id);

    if (dbRequest == null)
        throw new Exception("Not found");

    _mapper.Map<SiteCode>(request, dbRequest);

    await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This also give same error. I have fixed with `var result = await _techneDbContext.SiteCodes.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == request.Id);` .
Thank you.

Comment: And I have a doubt, Is this a best practice writing read operation in command? Or is this Okay writing `var dbRequest = await _DbContext.SiteCodes.FindAsync(request.Id);
` inside UpdateCommandHandler?

Comment: Do not use `AsNoTracking` of you plan to update entity. Probably you have left `Update` or `Attach` somewhere else.

Comment: OK Danyliv. Your answer is working fine. Thank you and  I did a mistake earlier that's why  i get error. Now This is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the method AsNoTracking() after SiteCodes to your query in Handler (GetSiteByIdQueryHandler.cs).

```
public async Task<SiteCode> Handle(GetSiteByIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    
    var result = await _DbContext.SiteCodes.AsNoTracking().FindAsync(request.Id);

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(nameof(SiteCode), request.Id);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Another approach you can do is create a repository and make use of Dapper

Comment: But I got thiss error.`'IQueryable<SiteCode>' does not contain a definition for 'FindAsync' and no accessible extension method 'FindAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<SiteCode>'`



Using FirstOrDefaultAsync is worked for me `var result = await _techneDbContext.SiteCodes.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == request.Id);`