# Update and Delete the nested object in Entity Framework Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I got this error, when I wanted to update product object:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

How can I  solve it?

**ProductsController**

```
[HttpPut("update/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> updateProduct(int id, [FromBody] ProductToUpdateDto updatingProduct)
{
    var p = _mapper.Map<Product>(updatingProduct);
    var r = await _productService.AddOrUpdateProduct(p);
    return Ok(r);
}
```

**ProductService**

```
public async Task<int?> AddOrUpdateProduct(Product product)
{
   var currentProduct = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().GetByIdAsync(product.Id, t => t.ProductCharacteristics);          

   foreach (var item in currentProduct.ProductCharacteristics)
   {
      var exist = product.ProductCharacteristics.ToList().Any(c => c.Id == item.Id);

      if (!exist)
      {
         _unitOfWork.Repository<ProductCharacteristic>().Delete(item);
      }
   }

   _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().AddOrUpdate(product);

   return await _unitOfWork.Complete();
}
```

**GenericRepository**

```
public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeRelatedTables)
{
   IQueryable<T> x = _context.Set<T>();

   foreach (var item in includeRelatedTables)
   {
      x = x.AsNoTracking().Include(item);
   }

   return await x.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
}

public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{
   _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
}

public virtual void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
{
   _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ShopDbContext _context;
    private Hashtable _repositories;

    public UnitOfWork(ShopDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<int> Complete()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        if (_repositories == null) 
           _repositories = new Hashtable();

        var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;

        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>);
            var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity)), _context);

            _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
        }

        return (IGenericRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
    }
}
```

Error:

> ERROR  Object { headers: {…}, status: 500, statusText: "Internal
> Server Error", url: "https://localhost:6001/api/products/update/7",
> ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response
> for https://localhost:6001/api/products/update/7: 500 Internal Server
> Error", error: "System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of
> entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with
> the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching
> existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
> key value is attached. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> conflicting key values.\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey
> key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry
> entry)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry
> entry)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState
> oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean
> modifyProperties)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState
> entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties,
> Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)\r\n
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1
> node, Func`2 handleNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry
> entry, EntityState entityState)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Update(TEntity entity)\r\n   at Lili.Shop.DataAccess.Repositories.GenericRepository`1.AddOrUpdate(T
> entity) in
> C:\Workspace\MainProjects\E-Shop\LiliShop-backend-dotnet\Lili.Shop\Main\Applications\Lili.Shop.DataAccess\Repositories\GenericRepository.cs:line
> 71\r\n   at
> Lili.Shop.Service.ProductService.AddOrUpdateProduct(Product product)
> in
> C:\Workspace\MainProjects\E-Shop\LiliShop-backend-dotnet\Lili.Shop\Main\Applications\Lili.Shop.Service\ProductService.cs:line
> 74\r\n   at
> Lili.Shop.API.Controllers.ProductsController.updateProduct(Int32 id,
> ProductToUpdateDto updatingProduct) in
> C:\Workspace\MainProjects\E-Shop\LiliShop-backend-dotnet\Lili.Shop\Main\Applications\Lili.Shop.API\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line
> 99\r\n   at lambda_method225(Closure, Object)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext
> actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor
> executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)\r\n   at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)\r\n   at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)\r\n\r\nHEADERS\r\n=======\r\nAccept: application/json,
> text/plain, */*\r\nHost: localhost:6001\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101
> Firefox/107.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate,
> br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAuthorization: Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InMuci5hbGVtQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJSb29oaSIsInJvbGUiOiJTdXBlckFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNjcwNTk4MDk4LCJleHAiOjE2NzEyMDI4OTgsImlhdCI6MTY3MDU5ODA5OCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NjAwMSJ9.1A9AJmJ52N-hUI1fZqaqfD4X6Y0v51B4z_K3MWQrHDg\r\nContent-Type:
> application/json\r\nOrigin: https://localhost:4200\r\nReferer:
> https://localhost:4200/\r\nTE: trailers\r\nContent-Length:
> 549\r\nsec-fetch-dest: empty\r\nsec-fetch-mode:
> cors\r\nsec-fetch-site: same-site\r\n" }

Comment: In the GenericRepository, I modified the AddOrUpdate method and it works well but I'm not sure that is the best way.


     public virtual void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
        {
            var trackedEntity = _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
            this._context.Entry<T>(trackedEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        }

Comment: I'd try to add `IQueryable<T> x = _context.Set<T().AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();` in `GetByIdAsync function`. I think here is the tracking problem. Then you should solve how to delete the item (ProductCharacteristic) when it's not loaded in the proxy.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583610/the-instance-of-entity-type-x-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with).